# How to create secure spring social registration / login that's painfree for the user

Tags: spring, facebook, oauth, spring-security, spring-social

My goal is to create a single click registration / sign on for my site using social media that's painfree yet secured using oauth and SocialAuthenticationFilter.

Ideally you'd be able to login to the same account with either twitter / Facebook etc (without first connecting them to a user account).

An example I'm working from is the Spring Social Showcase found on git, it's fantastic but it still requires an intermediary 'sign up' step.

I can't figure out a way of making a secure account using only the info from Facebook login using aouth and I'd prefer it if a user didn't have to sign up and connect as per the example.

So, is there a secure way of doing this or am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks

Comment: _“login to the same account with either twitter / Facebook etc (without first connecting them to a user account)”_ – that can only work if the user used the same e-mail address for both services, which is not a given.

Answer (score 0):

Using OAuth / OIDC is the right way to go.

In order to automatically match the logins from different social login providers, you have to rely on the email address as the primary user identifier.

Once relying on the email address, you may automatically register new users inside your internal DB.

However users may want to change their email address. This may complicate the processes significantly, depending on what options you want to support.